# Integrate other website into my website in iframe

Tags: iframe, laravel-5.8

I have to create a website where it compare results from 2 or more websites, these websites has to be integrated in my website's iframe, as done in " [here](https://www.kayak.co.in/) " for hotels

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwI9B.png)

Can anybody help me how to implement this feature in my website, I am using laravel 5.8

Comment: So you're looking for How to use iframe in html ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro not exactly iframe, but how to show other website in my own website, as i have shared the link for reference, and also the screenshort

Answer (score 0):

Alight here is an example of it

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row pt-10" id="iframeContainer">
      <div class="col-md-6">
           <h3 class="text-center">Website One</h3>
           <iframe id="iframe1" src="{{ $link1 }} " ></iframe>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
           <h3 class="text-center">Website Two</h3>
           <iframe id="iframe2" src="{{ $link2 }} "></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

in css

```
 #iframeContainer iframe{
   min-height: 550px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0px solid transparent;
 }
 .pt-10{
    padding-top:20px; 
 }
```

I'm sure this will work please give this a try

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what if i want to get the page with search parameters, as done in kayak.com, as we search hotels with some parameters in kayak, it shows both websites with all the results which match search parameters.

Comment: Now you're going bit far with far with this, it looks like you want to show someone elses results into your website

Comment: yes i want to show someone else result in my website as done in (https://www.kayak.co.in/s/compareresults/multi?providerCodes=BOOKINGDOTCOMIN_en_IN_HFDCMP2%2CAAEPRECHECKED_en_IN_HFDCMP2&searchId=ENEEOMnc36&pageOrigin=H..FD..M0)